# rails: how would you convert a multi-line output into html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, exec, whitespace

suppose in your controller, you had something like this:

```
@out = `git log --name-status -n1 ${@hash}`
```

(which returns a multi-line output to the terminal)

And you wanted to show it in a view like so:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, @out.html_safe, class: "well") %>
```

How do you get that output with preserved whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the good old `<pre>` tag or, in your CSS, apply [`white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the surrounding element. Personally I think `<pre>` is preferable, since it's semantic.

P.S. I would avoid using `html_safe` in this instance, as the unescaped output from your shell command could easily break your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a `<pre>` tag is used to markup pre-formatted text:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre